# Prestashop address limit show in order and my address

Tags: prestashop

I try to find the same problem as mine at google and stackoverflow, but I can not find it.

I have a problem with addresses....

I have customer who doesn't want to shop online from front office, they want to chat with me. To handle it, I use one customer and many addresses for shipping the order.

I want to record all the address. But yesterday and today, I found that I have added new address, but it doesn't show at the address list at the front office..... I found the address on the address list at the back office.

I use One Page Checkout. On the order summary page, which I have to choose the delivery address, the carrier, and the payment, I only get 28 addresses show on the dropdown.

It happen too at My Address in my Account. It shows only 28 addresses.

How can I open the limit? so I can show all the address for the customer.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by my own... its my bad.... it is because of the cache.... just clear the cache and it will show all the address.